# ObservableCollection

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, service, ria

Ive posted another thread regarding refreshing a silverlight listbox - In the meantime Ive become slightly more familiar with the issue. It has to do with implementing the ObservableCollection interface.

Im using RIA services to populate a listbox with a collection of type ObservableCollection. The problem is refreshing the Items once the database has been updated. I am using a silverlight child window to save the data to the database, and this is happening correctly On the close event of the child window.

Can anyone give me more information as to why the ListBox is not updating.

Thanks

Comment: did you try this one  listboxName.UpdateLayout();

Comment: Make sure your data binding is not set to OneTime. Are you sure the underlying data source is being updated?

Comment: Sounds like the underlying data source isn't getting updated after updating the database.  Can you confirm this?  Are you using two way binding on the listbox?

Comment: sorry - been away from this a while

DaveB - Yes, the underlying data source is being updated correctly

Myles - I am using oneway binding on the list box

Comment: Actually, Dave, Myles I think you have a point. The DB is being updated but the datasource might not be. The Listbox loads records based on a selection made in a datagrid. So, say I select row 1 on the datagrid, the listbox is populated correctly. I then add a new item to the listbox. The database is updated but not the listbox. If I select row 2 and then select row 1 again, the new record shows in the list box - must be the datasource? - If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your poco class that is used within your ObservableCollection implement INotifyChanged.

Example:

```
<viewModels:LocationsViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
.
.
.    
<ListView
    DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="GroupSection_ItemClick"
    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Latitude, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Longitude, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

public class LocationViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<Location> _locations = new ObservableCollection<Location>();
    public ObservableCollection<Location> Locations
    {
        get
        {
            return _locations;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_locations != value)
            {
                _locations = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Location : BaseViewModel
{
    int _locationId = 0;
    public int LocationId
    {
        get
        {
            return _locationId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_locationId != value)
            {
                _locationId = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    string _name = null;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    float _latitude = 0;
    public float Latitude 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _latitude;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_latitude != value)
            {
                _latitude = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    float _longitude = 0;
    public float Longitude
    {
        get
        {
            return _longitude;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_longitude != value)
            {
                _longitude = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    protected void OnNotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(memberName));
        }
    }
}
```